# Find closest element value (min & max) together with difference percentage

Tags: python, json

This is my sample list

```
def closest(lst, K):
    return lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-K))]

lst = [['0', '2.17'], ['1', '2.11'], ['2', '2.05'], ['3', '2.0'], ['4', '1.86'], ['5', '1.81'], ['6', '1.68'], ['7', '1.22'], ['8', '1.13'], ['9', '1.08'], ['10', '1.02'], ['11', '0.96'], ['12', '0.865'], ['13', '0.805'], ['14', '0.75'], ['15', '0.69'], ['16', '0.6'], ['17', '0.29'], ['18', '0.235'], ['19', '0.185']]

K = 0.545
print(closest(lst, K))
```

My expected output is

```
max= 0.6
min = 0.29
```

Also, I want to calculate percentage differences between min & max.

```
0.545 ~ 0.6  = 9.60699%
0.29 ~ 0.545 = 61.0778%
```

Comment: You must describe your problem, provide a bit of explanation of what you already tried and what you are hoping to achieve. Everything may not be clear only by the code you share.

Comment: What do you mean by max and min? 2 closest numbers to K which one is bigger than K and one is smaller than K?

Comment: Yes, nearest K. Nearest smaller and bigger than K

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the code you have added to the question doesn't actually work because the inner list having string values. Also, just adding the code is not going to help, you should explain what it is doing specifically `lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-K))]` part since the input is a 2D list, also add what the percentage difference between `min` and `max` look like. Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The code just example, not fully working.

Comment: how do you calculate that percentage? provide the formula

Answer (score 1):

You were looking for this:

```
mylist = [['0', '2.17'], ['1', '2.11'], ['2', '2.05'], ['3', '2.0'], ['4', '1.86'], ['5', '1.81'], ['6', '1.68'], ['7', '1.22'], ['8', '1.13'], ['9', '1.08'], ['10', '1.02'], ['11', '0.96'], ['12', '0.865'], ['13', '0.805'], ['14', '0.75'], ['15', '0.69'], ['16', '0.6'], ['17', '0.29'], ['18', '0.235'], ['19', '0.185']]
k = 0.545
limit = 100

m = min(mylist, key = lambda x: float(x[1]) - k if float(x[1]) >= k else limit)
n = min(mylist, key = lambda x: k - float(x[1]) if float(x[1]) <= k else limit)
print (m[1], n[1])

#my percentage calculate
print(float(m[1]) * 100 / k - 100)
print(100 - float(n[1]) * 100 / k)
```

`limit = 100` as a sentinel, here I put the greatest value

Output:

```
0.6 0.29
10.091743119266042
46.78899082568808
```

I still don't understand your percentage calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for finding the 2 closest numbers to K which one is bigger and one is smaller. Taking the number with the maximum distance from K and use it for once, taking the number with minimum distance to K which is **bigger** than K and once, for the number which is **smaller** than K.

```
def closest(lst, K):
    max_dist = float(max(lst, key = lambda x: abs(float(x[1])-K))[1])
    bigger = min(lst, key = lambda x: abs(float(x[1])-K) if float(x[1]) >= K else max_dist)
    smaller = min(lst, key = lambda x: abs(float(x[1]) - K) if float(x[1]) < K else max_dist)
    return [float(bigger[1]), float(smaller[1])]

lst = [['0', '2.17'], ['1', '2.11'], ['2', '2.05'], ['3', '2.0'], ['4', '1.86'], ['5', '1.81'], ['6', '1.68'], ['7', '1.22'], ['8', '1.13'], ['9', '1.08'], ['10', '1.02'], ['11', '0.96'], ['12', '0.865'], ['13', '0.805'], ['14', '0.75'], ['15', '0.69'], ['16', '0.6'], ['17', '0.29'], ['18', '0.235'], ['19', '0.185']]
K = 0.545
print(closest(lst, K))
```

**Output:**

```
[0.6, 0.29]
```

Comment: How about difference percentage K between min & max?

Comment: What is the expected result of that?

Comment: 0.545 ~ 0.6  = 9.60699%
0.29 ~ 0.545 = 61.0778%

Comment: @MohammadNurdin how do you get those numbers? the percentages? what exactly you divide or whatever?

Comment: Can you explain what calculation you have done for this percentage? because i tried doing (0.6-0.545)/0.545 but the result is about 10%

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to get the nearest two values (the first line requires Python 3.8 or higher but can be adjusted for older versions too) (also if there is no value on either side it will put None):

```py
def nearest(lst, k):
    (lst := [float(value) for index, value in lst]).append(k)  # get only the values and append k
    lst.sort()  # sort the list
    nearest_before = lst[nbi] if (nbi := lst.index(k) - 1) >= 0 else None  # get the value if the index is in list
    nearest_after = lst[nai] if (nai := lst.index(k) + 1) < len(lst) else None  # get the value if the index is in list
    return {'min': nearest_before, 'max': nearest_after}


sample_lst = [['0', '2.17'], ['1', '2.11'], ['2', '2.05'], ['3', '2.0'], ['4', '1.86'], ['5', '1.81'], ['6', '1.68'], ['7', '1.22'], ['8', '1.13'], ['9', '1.08'], ['10', '1.02'], ['11', '0.96'], ['12', '0.865'], ['13', '0.805'], ['14', '0.75'], ['15', '0.69'], ['16', '0.6'], ['17', '0.29'], ['18', '0.235'], ['19', '0.185']]

print(nearest(sample_lst, 0.545))
```

Output:

```
{'min': 0.29, 'max': 0.6}
```

(I returned a dict to keep clear which value is which but you can change that to whatever you need)

EDIT: made the function even more Python 3.8+ (again, it can be adjusted for older versions)

The only question is how do you want to calculate the percentage

Comment: this one more proper answer still got not percentage differences

Comment: @MohammadNurdin because you haven't explained how to calculate them

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

```
result_list = list()
K = 0.545
lst = [['0', '2.17'], ['1', '2.11'], ['2', '2.05'], ['3', '2.0'], ['4', '1.86'], ['5', '1.81'], ['6', '1.68'], ['7', '1.22'], ['8', '1.13'], ['9', '1.08'], ['10', '1.02'], ['11', '0.96'], ['12', '0.865'], ['13', '0.805'], ['14', '0.75'], ['15', '0.69'], ['16', '0.6'], ['17', '0.29'], ['18', '0.235'], ['19', '0.185']]
# Check for all number
for data in lst:
    result_list.append(float(data[1]))

# Finding min, max
max_dist = float(max(result_list, key = lambda x: abs(x-K)))
smaller  = min(result_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-K)if x <= K else max_dist)
bigger = min(result_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-K) if x >= K else max_dist)
# Finding percentage
per = smaller/bigger*100
print(smaller, bigger, per)
```

Result: `0.29 0.6 48.33`

Comment: The expected outcome not like this and not what I want.

Comment: so the output you want is 2 decimal place and lower than 1?